# How can I transform my data to a skewed normal distribution for a mixed effects model using stats.models?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, mixed-models, normal-distribution

I am using `statsmodels mixedlm` as follows:

```
model = smf.mixedlm("value ~ categorical_variable", data, groups=data[year_identifier])
```

[image]
When I plot the residuals I have a slightly left skewed distribution:

I tried to transform my response variable so that it was a skewed normal with a custom skew parameter:

```
# Define the custom skew-normal distribution with a custom skew parameter
skew_parameter = -4

# Transform response variable using the inverse CDF
data["transformed_value"] = stats.skewnorm.ppf(
    stats.norm.cdf(
        x=np.array(data["value"].values),
    ),
    skew_parameter,
)
```

And it resulted in all `np.inf` values.

I then tried to transform by adjusting the `loc` and `scale` values:

```
# Transform response variable using the inverse CDF
data["transformed_value"] = stats.skewnorm.ppf(
    stats.norm.cdf(
        x=np.array(data["value"].values),
        loc=np.mean(data["value"]),
        scale=np.std(data["value"]),
    ),
    skew_parameter,
)
```

This provided a transformed array, but when I plotted the residuals the distribution was actually *worse* and when I transformed them back, using the formula below, The values did not look correct at all:

```
result.params['Intercept'] = stats.skewnorm.cdf(result.params['Intercept'], skew_parameter)
result.params['categorical_variable[T.value]'] = stats.skewnorm.cdf(result.params['categorical_variable[T.value]'], skew_parameter)
```

Can anyone suggest what to do in this situation?

Perhaps I am not transforming correctly, or, maybe there is a better way to deal with a left-skewed normal distribution?